# Why my code is not working when I click on the same button for multiple times?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng

I have same Skip button types kept for 99 products. When I need to click that, it will bring a popup. In the popup I need to click the Cancel button. Each time when I click on the Skip buton it will give a popup like this.

[image: popup]

So I used this code. it is working up to a point of time and throwing an error.

My code is

```
package Backendsite;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SkipTest {
    @Test
    public void f() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");

        // Setting To Open Incoginoto Window
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("-incognito");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        WebDriver chromedriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        chromedriver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Opening The WebSite
        chromedriver.get("xxxxxxxxxxx");

        chromedriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Pomsite p1 = PageFactory.initElements(chromedriver, Pomsite.class);

        Select s1 = new Select(p1.getE1());
        s1.selectByVisibleText("xxxxxxxxxxxx");


        Thread.sleep(3000);

        List<WebElement> elements = chromedriver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_')]"));


        Thread.sleep(2000);

        for (Iterator<WebElement> iterator = elements.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        {


            WebElement webElement = (WebElement) iterator.next();

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            webElement.click();

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            chromedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']")).click();
        }
```

The Exception error is ,

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

*PS: Sometimes I see Stale Element Reference Error.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a break inside the for loop. This will resolve you from Stale element Reference exception. Try the below code

```
 for (Iterator<WebElement> iterator = elements.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {


        WebElement webElement = (WebElement) iterator.next();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        webElement.click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        chromedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']")).click();

    break;

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how a break in a for loop will solve the OP's problems

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. There is definitely synchronization issue. This is primarily due to the Component or page load strategy.
The elegant solution to this could be have a *explicit wait* to check for the *intractability* of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to skip clicking on currently invisible elements (may be they have become invisible during loop execution) with try/catch block:

```
try {
    webElement.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    chromedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']")).click();
catch (ElementNotVisibleException ex) {
    // do logging
}
```

Or add second catch for Stale Element Reference Error.

BTW: It would be better if you point out the line of code where these errors occure.